# How to specialize a template member function depending on the class' template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I would like to write this:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class OK
{
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;

public:
    template<typename TX> const TX & GetRef() const;
};

template<typename T1,typename T2>
template<>
const T1 & OK<T1,T2>::GetRef<T1>() const { return t1; }

template<typename T1,typename T2>
template<>
const T2 & OK<T1,T2>::GetRef<T2>() const { return t2; }
```

Which VS10 fails to compile.

To check my understanding of template specialization, I tried and compiled this all right:

```
typedef int  T1;
typedef char T2;
class OK
{
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;

public:
    template<typename TX> const TX & GetRef() const;
};

template<>
const T1 & OK::GetRef<T1>() const { return t1; }

template<>
const T2 & OK::GetRef<T2>() const { return t2; }
```

What am I missing? Is what I want to do even possible?

**Edit**: I'd like to have getters for all fields, all called `GetRef()`, so the user can write something like:

```
OK<float,double> ok;
float a = ok.GetRef<float>();
double b = ok.GetRef<double>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot specialize a member template of a class template without specializing the template. That is, either you provide a full specialization on which `T1` and `T2` are fixed on the class template and then `TX` can also be fixed or you cannot fix `TX`.

The simple solution is not to specialize the template function, but rather provide a different overload:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class OK
{
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
public:
    const T1& GetRef() const { return t1; }
    template<typename TX> const TX & GetRef() const;
};
```

Comment: I see. I guess I cannot provide a getter for t2 also called GetRef, then.

Comment: @Gabriel: Nope... I guess I don't really understand what you are trying to do overall, but why don't you provide two different functions that return each member? If what you want is a `GetRef` that will return either option based on the type, then you can add an extra level of indirection to resolve it: `template <typename T> T const& get() const { return get( (T*)0 ); }; T1 const & get( T1* ) { return t1; } T2 const & get( T2* ) { return t2; }` where the two non-template `get` would be private.

Comment: Nice ! This does the trick ! (You forgot the consts on the private gets BTW) Thank you !